# Rails-Passing an object to a DB method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm wondering whether the following is possible in Rails. I'm pretty new to Rails, but it just seems like the type of thing I would expect Rails to make possible...

I am wondering whether a DB method (for example, `find`) can take an object and *know automatically* to look for its ID value in the appropriate foreign key column without being given the name of that column.

My specific use case is that I would like to make a **generic** method that checks whether two models are correlated via a connection-table or not.

(In other words, different tables will be linking different models, and thus will use different column names. I want to be able to pass in something [presumably objects of the relevant classes] and Rails will know that the `id` of `@sample_model` of class `SampleModel` should be searched for in the column `sample_model_id`.)

So the method would be something like:

```
def connected? (connection_table, model1, model2)
    connection_table.class.find_by(model1, model2)
end
```

…and the method could know automatically that it's looking for model1.id in the model1_id column and the model2.id in the model2_id column.

Is this (or something like it) possible? If not, is there any other way to accomplish my goal (the generic-connection-checker method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method should work as expected:

```ruby
def self.find_by(obj1, obj2)
  fk_1, fk_2 =
    [obj1, obj2].map { |o| self.reflect_on_association(o.class.to_s.split("::").last.underscore.to_sym).foreign_key }
  self.where(fk_1 => obj1, fk_2 => obj2).last
end
```

Comment: I don't understand everything you wrote here, but it looks like this assumes it knows the names of `fk_1` and `fk_2`…? I am trying to make a generic method that can be used for different objects/tables which have different column names… (I think that wasn't clear in my Q, though--will edit)

Comment: In this code, I'm clearly making assumptions on the belongs_to format. If you don't want to do this, you can use the ```self.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to)``` method to retrieve all the belongs_to associations and keep the ones you're interested into.